# Why do I get this warning when using a null conditional operator?

Tags: unity, c#

In the OnTriggerEnter2D function of my Bullet script, I have the following code:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
     if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
     {
         var enemy = other.GetComponent<Enemy>();
         enemy?.Death();
     }
}
```

The reason for the null conditional operator (the question mark) in `enemy?.Death()` is because the Death function actually destroys the Enemy component script, 
so it suppresses an error when the bullet hits the enemy again. It's supposed to be shorthand for:

```
if (enemy != null)
    enemy.Death();
```

The code works; the error is suppressed. However, the IDE that I'm using, Jetbeans Rider, gives the following warning:

> '?.' on a type deriving from 'UnityEngine.Object' bypasses the
>   lifetime check on the underlying Unity object.

What does that mean exactly? Should I continue using the null conditional operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because Unity overrides the `==` operator (and therefore `!=`), changing its behavior, and the `?.` operator does not use their version.

For more information, see [Custom == operator, should we keep it?](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/).

To summarize: Unity objects are wrappers around a C/C++ object. When that object is `Destroy()`ed, the underlying C++ object is also destroyed but the C# object has to wait until it is garbage collected.

That also means that *you should not compare to null*, and instead do:

```
var enemy = other.GetComponent<Enemy>();
if (enemy)
    enemy.Death();
```

Another reference: [Don't Use == null On Unity Objects](https://jacx.net/2015/11/20/dont-use-equals-null-on-unity-objects.html)

Comment: So as I understand it, calling `Destroy(Enemy);` destroys the native c++ object, and the null conditional operator will check for that, so why should I care that the actual c# object is not destroyed?

Comment: The problem is that the null conditional operator **will not** check for that, as the warning describes ("bypasses the lifetime check"). It checks whether the C# object is `null`, which in general it might not be, even if it's been destroyed. So you might try to double-destroy an already-destroyed component.  In your specific case you're probably safe - `GetComponent` should return a real `null` if there's no non-destroyed component of that type. But the IDE doesn't know that, so it warns you about a potential error you *could* run into with this construct, say if using a cached reference.